# Is it possible to open a link in chrome from a java coded application whose default browser id internet explorer

Tags: java, browser

I have java/.jsp coded application for which default browser is internet explorer. This application home page has few links that opens in internet explorer, but those few links now need to be open in chrome. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of default browser behavior. If this is web application, you can't control the default browser. If your application is desktop and then you can partially control by providing the installer which can change the default browser given that user has admin rights.